# Potential inside a polarized sphere

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage

When you are inside some non uniformly and non radially polarized sphere, why do the dipoles from outer shells don't affect you (the potential there is only due to inner dipoles from what I have seen)?

Answer (score 0):

That is not true in general. If you are given the polarization vector $\vec{P}$ in the sphere, then you can calculate the polarization charges, which in general will be volume charges $\rho_{_P}=-\nabla\cdot\vec{P}$ inside the sphere and surface charges. Surface charge densities $\sigma_{_{P}}$ are only present wherever the normal component of $\vec{P}$ to the surface has a discontinuity. That usually happens at the surface of the sphere, outside of which $\vec{P}=\vec{0}$.

Then, you can calculate the electric potential as the potential that these charges create. For a non-uniform and non-radial polarization, the polarization charge density does not need to have spherical symmetry and Gauss's law has no practical use in this case. So in general the electric field or the potential at one point a distance $r$ from the origin is not only the one due to the inner charge in a sphere of radius $r$. You would need to do the whole integral
$$\phi(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\int_{V'}\frac{\rho_{_P}(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}dv'$$

Comment: When is it true then? I have a case with a charge density $\rho = 2arcos\theta$ and it is unsolvable when integrating. I know it is possible to consider only the charges inside in this case, but I have no idea why.

Comment: @darkenin Is that an arccosine or a constant $a$ times $r$ times a cosine? By the way, how do you know for sure that what you say is possible?

Comment: some constant $a$. I know because I have the answers, but I don't understand  why it is this way. I calculated the electric field outside by treating the polarized sphere as a single dipole by integrating polarization density over the entire volume but I can't use this trick inside the sphere because treating the polarized sphere like a dipole isn't right when inside.